# How to specify nonlinear Bayesian regression model?

Tags: bayesian, generalized-linear-model

I'm a little confused about how to specify a regression model in Bayesian terms. I understand that for the simple case of plain linear regression, the response variable is normally distributed about the mean, which varies linearly, like so:
$$
Y \sim N(\beta X, \sigma)
$$
where $\beta$ and $\sigma$ are drawn from priors and an intercept can also be added.

My data (sample shown below) are roughly exponentially shaped. Values can be zero, but not negative. My first impulse was to try a model with $Y \sim N(\lambda e^{-\lambda X},\sigma)$, but I'm not sure if this makes sense and, anyway, it would allow for negative values but shouldn't.

Ultimately, my goal is to estimate the **variance along this curve**, getting a distribution as a function of the variable on the horizontal axis.

Is there a standard approach?

[image]

Comment: why are the circles filled with different colours and have different diameters? Do you perhaps have more than one feature?

Comment: Yes I do. Markers are colored by the same feature as the horizontal axis, so that's no issue. Marker sizes represent another feature, but I don't necessarily need to include it in the model.

Comment: Great. Another thing, you are asking about two different things (1) Bayesian regression, (2) regression for the variance. In (1) Iguess  you want to model the mean. Do you have any prior information? Is there any motivation about (2) ?

Comment: Yes I want to model the mean and estimate the variance as a function of the same feature  on the horizontal axis. I know that the response variable can never be negative.

Answer (score 2):

You can always apply transformations to your x and y values before doing Bayesian Linear Regression. This looks a lot like power-law to me, so I would try taking the logarithm of both x and y. Here the assumption is that y is log-normally distributed for a given x. If that isn't enough you can first transform your y data to cover the entire reals and then apply a Gaussian Processes, which assumes that the transformed ys are joint normally distributed for a set of xs.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I'm still in the process of understanding what particular distribution `Y` assumes under these transformations.

Comment: For Bayesian Linear Regression and Gaussian Processes you always assume that your ys are in a multivariate normal distribution for a set of xs when applying the model (so after the transformation). To check whether such a transformation even exists, you can potentially check whether copula of different Ys is Gaussian.

Comment: It might also be interesting to check out these papers:
https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2003/hash/6b5754d737784b51ec5075c0dc437bf0-Abstract.html
https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2010/file/fc8001f834f6a5f0561080d134d53d29-Paper.pdf

Comment: Does it make sense to use a model in the form: $\log Y \sim N(\beta X + \alpha, \gamma X)$

where $\beta$, $\alpha$, and $\gamma$ are the parameters to estimate